# Externalize Spring Boot application.properties on windows not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I build executable jar file(using gradle) of my spring-boot app:

I put application.properties file somewhere in my comp. for example:

/etc/test/application.properties

I run my jar this way:

```
java -jar my-app-0.0.1.jar --spring.config.location=etc/test/application.properties
```

I get error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: you said you put it in "/etc/test", but the properties says "etc/test". 
So he searches subfolders "etc/test" in your current folder isn't it ?

Comment: I found the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `-Dspring.config.location=file:/etc/test/application.properties` (I've tested it on windows with  `-Dspring.config.location=file:c:\application.properties`)

Comment: It's important to notice that `-jar` *must be after* the `-D` properties set.

Answer (score 3):

Problem was that I had additional annotation:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

which always override it